# Given the function $y = 3 \sin(2x + \pi/3) - 4$, find the amplitude, period, phase shift and vertical displacement?

Tags: calculus

Given the function $y = 3 \sin(2x + \pi/3) - 4$, find the amplitude, period, phase shift and vertical displacement?

Can someone show me how to do this? I tried to solve I think I got write answer it would be great to see how you would attempt this question thanks.
Amplitude: 3
Period: $\pi$
Phase shift: to the right by $\pi/2$
Vertical displacement: down by 4

Answer (score 1):

The amplitude is how high up the function goes from the x-axis; $y = sin(x)$ only goes up to $1$, and because you're multiplying the function by $3$, the highest point becomes $3$; thus, the amplitude is $3$.

The period is how often the function repeats itself; $y = sin(x)$ normally repeats every $2\pi$ radians, but in this case you're also multiplying $2x$, and so the period becomes $\frac{2\pi}{2} = \pi$. So the period is $\pi$.

The phase shift is just its leftwards translation. You've moved it to the left $-\frac{\pi}{3}$ times, and so really it's just that amount to the right. So the phase shift is rightwards $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Finally, the vertical displacement is found by how much the function is subtracted by; in this case, you subtract $y = sin(x)$ by $4$, and so the vertical displacement is $4$ downwards.

And so all of your answers are correct, besides the phase shift (though I suspect that's just a typo).

Answer (score 0):

The amplitude, period and vertical displacement are correct, but the phase shift is wrong. To find the phase shift, you'd first have to isolate the function x, like this:
2(x+pi/6)
so the phase shift is pi/6 units to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remember the general formula of a sinusoid: $$y=a\sin(b(x-c))+d$$

$a$: amplitude

$\frac{2\pi}{b}$: period

$c$: horizontal displacement: $c$ to right

$d$: vertical displacement: up by $d$

As to this particular example: $$y=3\sin(2x+\frac{\pi}{3})-4=3\sin(2(x+\frac{\pi}{6}))-4$$

Amplitude: $3$

Period: $\frac{2\pi}{2}=\pi$

Horizontal displacement: $\frac{\pi}{6}$ to left

Vertical displacement: $4$ downwards